# Getting one row sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below table

```
Id          Stack
------------------
1             a
1             b
2             c
2             d
```

I want to get below table result.

```
Id          Stack
------------------
1             a
2             c
```

I use DISTINCT but it doesnot work
how can I do it ?
are there any solution by using group by?

Comment: Which database server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE table sampletb(id int, stack varchar(10));

INSERT into sampletb values(1,'a');
INSERT into sampletb values(1,'b');
INSERT into sampletb values(2,'c');
INSERT into sampletb values(2,'d');

SELECT * FROM sampletb;

id          stack
----------- ----------
1           a
1           b
2           c
2           d


SELECT id,
       stack,
       row_number() over (partition by id order by stack) as row_number
from   sampletb;
```

This query will give you result like this.

```
id          stack      row_number
----------- ---------- --------------------
1           a          1
1           b          2
2           c          1
2           d          2
```

Now making the above query as subquery and getting the columns having
`row_number=1` will give the desire output you wanted.

```
select id,stack from 
       (
       SELECT id,
              stack,
              row_number() over (partition by id order by stack) as row_number 
       FROM   sampletb) x
where  x.row_number=1;

id          stack
----------- ----------
1           a
2           c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id,stack from (
select id , stack  , row_number() over (partition by id order by stack) as rn
) k where rn=1
```

Comment: Surely you want `order by stack` not `order by id` otherwise the query is non deterministic? i.e. either a or b could be returned as the stack for ID = 1.

Comment: yeah. I guess it will be better. Also , I think that if he sees [1,1,1,1] so it will be considered as the order they been _inserted_ to db which will yield the right result. . However - it _is_better to sort by stack.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of your exact logic that needs to be applied, but this would return the results you have posted:

```
SELECT  ID, MIN(Stack) AS Stack
FROM    T
GROUP BY ID
```

You can use more advanced logic with the `ROW_NUMBER` function if your DBMS allows it (none tagged in the question)

```
SELECT  ID, Stack
FROM    (   SELECT  ID,
                    Stack,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Stack) AS RowNumber
            FROM    T
        ) t
WHERE   RowNumber = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
select Id, min(Stack) from <TABLE_NAME>
group by Id
```