# Next/previous record based on current

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table which is not sorted by any of column. Is there any way to select next/previous record if I know only Id of current? (I'm using mssql)

```
Id     Label     Date
---------------------
1      label1    2011-01-10
7      label2    2011-01-15 -- how to get previous?
5      label3    2011-01-12 -- I know id of this record
10     label10   2011-01-25 -- how to get next?
12     label8    2011-01-13
2      label5    2011-01-29
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which version ? if it is 2012 sql server than look at **lead && lag** http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/

Comment: what is the query used to get those results ?

Comment: The query could be different but I want to create one stored procedure for all queries

Comment: again , for your question : what is the query used to get those results ? I need the order by clause here in order to give you an answer

Comment: for example it is select * from MyTable

Comment: sorry my friend - youll have to provide order by clause

Comment: have a look at my question about this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402524/does-sql-server-minds-the-way-records-where-inserted

Comment: Ok, as I understood I need to use row_number()... This will be my order clause. And how my query will look like in this case?

Comment: `row_number()` must use `order by`  - again ! what is your order by clause ? :-)

Comment: I'm confused... So no way to make it without order clause?

Comment: SELECT clause with out the ORDER BY does not set any sorting at all. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923366/getting-last-record-from-mysql?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want the previous from the list you enclosed, here is a way.

```
declare @t table(Id int, Label varchar(10), Date date, s int identity(1,1))
insert @t (id, label, date) 
values(1,'label1','2011-01-10'),(7,'label2','2011-01-15'),
(5,'label3','2011-01-12'),(10,'label10','2011-01-25'),
(12,'label8','2011-01-13'),(2,'label5','2011-01-29')

--select the data with a self join

select t1.id as previous_id, t2.id, t2.Label, t2.Date, t3.id, t3.id as next_id
from @t t1
right join
@t t2 on t1.s + 1 = t2.s
left join
@t t3  on t2.s = t3.s - 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure I got what is s column. I have no this coulmn in table. Do you want me to create it?

Comment: Id, Label, Date are the columns. I don't want you to create new columns, I just want you to populate the temporary table with the data you have, then you can link the rows to the previous rows

Comment: Well, it works for previous, thanks! And how I can modify this to see next and previous at the same time?

Comment: @Vytalyi I now noticed you wanted both the next and the previous, so i modified my script to include both

Comment: Yeah, looks like it works. Not a standard solution but I think I can do this until find something better. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
VALUES (1, 'label1', '2011-01-10'), (7, 'label2', '2011-01-15'),
       (5, 'label3', '2011-01-12'), (10, 'label10', '2011-01-25'),             
       (12, 'label8', '2011-01-13'), (2, 'label5', '2011-01-29')

select * from table007; 

Declare @inptID int=12;

;WITH CTE 
as
(
   select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 0)) as rn 
   from table007
 )

select * 
from CTE 
where rn in( select rn-1 from CTE where id = @inptID)
union all
select * from CTE where rn in(select rn + 1 from CTE where id = @inptID);
```

SQL Fiddle Demo

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4cf3f/4)

Comment: Something wrong with this query... It returns not what I want... Give me 3 minutest and I will attach the screenshot

Comment: whatever you have explained in your question abobe its doing correctly

Comment: Could you please look on screenshot? Any ideas?

Comment: cann you pls show only discussionthreadid,rn column in the screenshot  there?

Comment: is is 708 and 710. Is it what you asking?

Comment: i want to see rn column in the screen shot

Comment: I see that it very close to what I want... but could you please help me to finish this?

Comment: I cant see the rn column there

Comment: just select discussionthreadid and rn columns from your table and put results in screenshot

Comment: yeah i got it.But did you check my Fiddle Demo there its working properly.can you put your table with sample data in fiddle i wil check

Comment: waht position i did not get you?

Comment: Mys solution should work for your requirement.I guess there is a small tweaking needs to be done for your table

Comment: if you could atleast give me your table structure i can try to solve it

Answer (score 3):

If it is not sorted by any column, there is no definitive next or previous record. Data in SQL Server has no order, other than that specified by an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: As you said there will not be any order but as per my understanding when data gets stored in memory,it just appends to the last inserted row.So thats what OP also wants.I mean he wants to get previous and next row from heap.